# How to enable 'Insert Activex Control' in Visual Studio 2012 for a Win32 Dialog based application?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2012, dialog, activex

I am new to `ActiveX Controls`, though I have some basic background in COM/ATL programming.

#### Steps

The project is a simple Win32 project created using the Visual Studio 2012 wizard. I have selected all the default options. The dialog box is created using the resource editor dialog and then selecting *new dialog* option.

#### Problem

In my application I want to host the Internet Explorer (or some other) activex control in a dialog box. But the problem is that when I right click (as suggested by many sites and even msdn) the `insert activex control ...` is always disabled. I am **not using** MFC, but instead `CAxDialogImpl` [(as described here)](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/Win32_dialoghelpers.html).

Please suggest what I am doing wrong? How can I enable `insert activex control ...` in Visual Studio 2012 dialog editor?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I took considerable time to enable it, but the answer is simple: remove the macro "_APS_NO_MFC" in "resource.h" file.

Answer (score 0):

A plain Win32 dialog does not have ActiveX container support, so the resource editor will not let you add the control.

You'll need to create a second project like an MFC dialog-based app, then copy the control information from its RC file.

CodeProject has some articles on using ActiveX controls without MFC, such as this one using parts of ATL - [Win32 dialog helpers](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3947/Win-dialog-helpers) or this one that's pure C++ but similar to ATL's AxWindow - [Use an ActiveX control in your Win32...](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18417/Use-an-ActiveX-control-in-your-Win-Project-witho)