# How to use activex dll inside an ATL project?

Tags: c++, atl, ocx

In Windows application project I can simply add it (ocx file) as a reference.

After registering the activex using regsvr32. My question is how do I use/add/load this 3rd party activex (ocx file) inside the ATL project? Pardon me, I am new to creating an ATL project.

Working environment:
-Visual C++ 2010

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveX control is consumed in an ATL project via COM either fully from code or with the help of certain ATL classes. A simple example is ATL [`CAxDialogImpl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3td1y6hh) class which is an implementation of a modal or modeless dialog class, with support for ActiveX controls. Note that Visual Studio dialog designer is capable of interactive insertion of ActiveX control into dialog template so that `CAxDialogImpl` could pick it up on runtime.

- [How to enable 'Insert Activex Control' in Visual Studio 2012 for a Win32 Dialog based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20466195/how-to-enable-insert-activex-control-in-visual-studio-2012-for-a-win32-dialog)
- [CDialogImpl, CAxDialogImpl, and CSimpleDialog](http://www.icodeguru.com/vc%26mfc/InsideAtl/ch14f.htm)

Comment: Hi Roman,

"The ActiveX control is consumed in an ATL project via COM either fully from code or with the help of certain ATL classes"

I have an ocx file, and I want to load it on my ATL project, can you please show me a sample code to use it?

My approach is something like this:

HMODULE m_hDLL ;
m_hDLL = LoadLibraryW(ocx_path);

U_close = (U_CLOSE)GetProcAddress(m_hDLL, "Close");

where U_CLOSE was declared as [typedef short (WINAPI* U_CLOSE)();]
Close is an expose method from that ocx file.

Thanks